# Facing Yerushalaim during Kaddish

Tags: geography, kaddish

Must one face Yerushlaim (or the Hechal) when reciting Kaddish,the way one should for Amida? This seems to be generally practiced; does it have a source in the Shulchan Aruch or achronim or is it a misconception?

Comment: I once asked my rav and he said it was unnecessary.

Comment: @l' While we're at it, many also place their feet together.

Comment: @YDK yesh ladun. see terumat hadeshen 28.

Comment: @DoubleAA, I had that svara, but I never saw it inside.  Y"C

Comment: perhaps related for those who bow during kaddish http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/10495/759

Comment: @DoubleAA I've seen Poskim that say like your Rav.

Comment: HaRav Eliyahu Mansour, SheLYT"A, just addressed this in his Daily Halacha ([link](http://www.dailyhalacha.com/m/halacha.aspx?id=2723))

Answer (score 4):

One of the main reasons why we pray towards Yerushalayim is to display our yearning for the Bet Hamikdash to be rebuilt.

The other reason being that it's the "Gates of Heaven" where prayers go up - whatever that means.

Since Kadish is both (1) a prayer (2) for the Bet Hamikdash to be rebuilt it would make sense to face the Bet Hamikdash while reciting it. However, it's not mentioned in classical sources, AFAIK.

Comment: Sources for your first two paragraphs would help a lot.