# Facing east when standing in prayers

Tags: tefilla, standing-sitting

I was praying with my kid in a synagogue wherein the [*aron*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Torah_ark) was against the eastern wall, and most of the seats were facing north or south. My kid wondered why the people around us turned to face east whenever they were standing. I had (and have) no idea. (Of course, they face east for the *amida* and so on. But then also for "*Alenu*" and *shir shel yom* and *kadish* (even those not saying it) et cetera.) Anyone know?

Comment: related http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/15382/759

Comment: related http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/10495/759

Comment: Since this has no answers yet, and since my kid has (on another occasion in the same synagogue) expanded the scope of the question, and since http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/468?m=9391119#9391119 et seq., I'm editing this question to be about not just "_Alenu_".

Comment: Were you worried about misrepresenting your kid online? :)